# WCF Service: Client Principal Delegation between WebServices

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, identity-delegation

I'm currently developing a website which uses multiple WCF-WebServices.

Delegation and Impersonation haven't been a problem yet.

Now I have the following scenario:

WebSite --> WebService1 --> Validation-WebService

My Website calls the WebService1 (which is the core of the system) and WebService1 calls my Validation-WebService.
WebService1 and the Validation-WebService are currently running on the same machine in differnent virtual directories. It is possible that the services are running on different machines in production mode, that's why I want to use delegation instead of impersonation. Both are running under the following context: "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE".

In both WebServices I want to identify the actual user of the WebSite, which - in my case - currently works via `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name`.

I am able to get the WindowsIndentity of the user in the first WebService, but not in the Validation-WebService.

If I require impersonation on the intermediate WebService via `[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]` I'm getting an exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://myWebServer.myCompany.com/ValidationService_dev/ValidationService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'myWebServer.myCompany.com'
```

If I'm not impersonating in WebService1, the connection works but the identification in the Validation-WebService fails.

WebService1 has the following configuration (just important parts):

```
<services>
  <service name="WebService1.WebService1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IWebService1" contract="WebService1.IWebService1">
      <identity>
        <servicePrincipalName value="host/myWebServer.myCompany.com"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceAuthenticationManager authenticationSchemes="IntegratedWindowsAuthentication" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CredentialDelegationBehavior">
      <clientCredentials>
        <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Delegation" />
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IValidationService">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IWebService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
      allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://myWebServer.myCompany.com/ValidationService_dev/ValidationService.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IValidationService" behaviorConfiguration="CredentialDelegationBehavior"
    contract="ValidationService.IValidationService" name="WSHttpBinding_IValidationService">
    <identity>
      <servicePrincipalName value="host/myWebServer.myCompany.com" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

Delegation is configured and looks similar to the config of the WebSite (which works).

Configuration of Validation-WebService (just important parts):

```
<services>
  <service name="ValidationService.ValidationService" >
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IValidationService" contract="ValidationService.IValidationService">
      <identity>
        <servicePrincipalName value="host/myWebServer.myCompany.com"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>


<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceAuthenticationManager authenticationSchemes="IntegratedWindowsAuthentication" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IValidationService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
     receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
     transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
     maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
     messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
     allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
       maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
       enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
         realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I've already found one forum post which describes the exact same problem, but this didn't work for me :(
Here: [Forum Post found](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d07a42f6-b52b-4620-af84-7eda2e7348f7/passing-windowsidentity-between-services-for-use-with-azman?forum=wcf)

Has anybody a suggestion on how this could work?
I'm working on this since two days and wasn't able to find a solution.

If you need any other information, feel free to ask.